# The type javax.servlet.ServletContext and javax.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, servlets, spring-security

I'm trying to include Spring Security to my web project, i'm following this tutorial http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//helloworld.html

I've done everything in the tutorial with the given maven project and works fine. But when i'm trying to include it to my project a compilation error appear. Specifically when i extends from `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` appear the given error

[image: Code with the error]

[image: The floating compilation error]

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The type javax.servlet.ServletContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
> - The type javax.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

The POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>spring.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces.testwebapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SpringPrimefacesWebApp</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- JSF 2.2 core and implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Prime Faces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Thanks for the help!

Using mvn clean install -U

[image]

Comment: Without the relevant portions of your pom it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: Sorry, I just uploaded the complete pom.

Comment: execute command from command prompt(execute from the directory where POM is kept).          mvn clean install -U. If this does not work check apache-maven-3.3.1\conf\settings.xml file for repository path

Comment: @Vinayak I'm just checking the setting file but, where/what is the repository path thing?

Comment: Same error found for SprintBoot App, its strange when by default spring boot starter dependency in pom and still asking for ServletContex

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just add the [`javax.servlet` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) to the compile time dependencies. You don't need to include it in the build, it's already provided by the target servlet container.

Your current pom suggests that you're deploying to a barebones servlet container ([Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org), [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), etc) instead of a full fledged Java EE application server ([WildFly](https://wildfly.org), [TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org), GlassFish, [Liberty](https://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/appserv-was-liberty-core), etc), otherwise you'd have run into classloading-related trouble by providing JSF along with the webapp instead of using the container-provided one.

In that case, adding the below dependency should do for a [Servlet 3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0) container like Tomcat 8:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or if you're actually targeting an older [Servlet 3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1) container like Tomcat 7, change the `<version>` to `3.0.1` (note: there's no `3.0` due to a mistake on their side).

If you happen to actually deploy to a [Java EE 7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) application server like WildFly 8, use the below dependency instead. It covers the entire [Java EE API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/), including `javax.servlet` (and `javax.faces`, so you'd then remove those individual JSF API/impl dependencies):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also here, if you're targeting an older [Java EE 6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/6.0) application server like JBoss AS 7, change the `<version>` to `6.0`.

#### See also:

- [How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/how-to-properly-configure-jakarta-ee-libraries-in-maven-pom-xml-for-tomcat/65704617#65704617)

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me: if above supplied solution doesnt work
Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add library from library tab > Choose server runtime > Next > choose Apache Tomcat v 7.0> Finish > Ok

Answer (score 2):

another way if you working on eclipse ide please open the project folder select Properties and click maven shows the view 'Active Maven Profiles(comma separated)'please input  "dev"..after refresh problem solved

Answer (score 0):

try setting the updated parent, like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

this solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me was deleting the repository in directory .m2
and after deleting run maven: package