# Tomcat 10.x throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on javax.servlet.*

Tags: tomcat, servlets, noclassdeffounderror

Deployed servlet based web application at context path [/VirtualStore], but context failed to start with below log.

```
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.075 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\conf\Catalina\localhost\VS.xml] has finished in [448] ms
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\docs]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.291 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [143] milliseconds.
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.306 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\docs] has finished in [228] ms
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.307 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\examples]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\examples] has finished in [307] ms
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\host-manager]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [32] ms
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\manager]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\manager] has finished in [29] ms
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\ROOT]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [27] ms
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.708 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:35.726 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1894] milliseconds
19-Mar-2021 11:46:36.546 INFO [http-nio-8085-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/VirtualStore]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:36.562 INFO [http-nio-8085-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\conf\Catalina\localhost\VirtualStore.xml]
19-Mar-2021 11:46:36.563 WARNING [http-nio-8085-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/VirtualStore] in deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\conf\Catalina\localhost\VirtualStore.xml] has been ignored
19-Mar-2021 11:46:36.934 SEVERE [http-nio-8085-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-10.0.4\conf\Catalina\localhost\VirtualStore.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:692)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:540)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1777)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1570)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1022)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/VirtualStore]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:866)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1370)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1086)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:664)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5115)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
        ... 60 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Tomcat can convert an existing web application from Java EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9 at deployment time using the Apache Tomcat migration tool for Jakarta EE. To make use of the feature, the web application should be placed in the Host legacyAppBase folder (by default named webapps-javaee) and they will be converted to an equivalent Jakarta EE web application in the Host appBase folder (by default named webapps). https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html#Migrating_from_9.0.x_to_10.0.x

Answer (score 56):

According to your logs,

> C:\Users\Ing.Girbson BIJOU\Documents\NetBeansProjects\apache-tomcat-10.0.4-windows-x64\**apache-tomcat-10.0.4**\conf\Catalina\localhost\VirtualStore.xml

you're thus using Tomcat 10.x which is based off Servlet API version 5.0 which in turn is part of Jakarta EE version 9.

However, this exception is unexpected:

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener`

Basically, the deployed web application is looking for `javax.servlet.*`, but it should actually be looking for `jakarta.servlet.*`. Namely, the `javax.*` package has been renamed to `jakarta.*` package since Jakarta EE version 9. This thus means that the deployed web application is actually not compatible with Jakarta EE version 9. The deployed web application is most likely developed for an older JEE version where the `javax.*` package is still used.

So, summarized, the targeted JEE versions don't match up and it's causing trouble for you. You have 2 options:

1. Downgrade Tomcat to version 9.x. This is the latest available version which still uses the `javax.*` package. This is however not the recommended option in long term as the `javax.*` package is clearly a dead end for JEE.
2. Or, upgrade the deployed web application to target Jakarta EE 9+ instead. I.e. adjust the project's dependencies (e.g. `pom.xml`) to reference JEE 9+ based versions instead, and then perform a project-wide Find & Replace of `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` (of course except for `javax.naming.*` and `javax.xml.*` and [probably a few others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364511/how-to-handle-javax-net-and-javax-sql-imports-while-upgrading-to-springboot-3/76364735#76364735), but the Java compiler will quickly point out them for you).

#### See also:

- [Apache Tomcat - Versions](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)
- [How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/tomcat-9-casting-servlets-to-javax-servlet-servlet-instead-of-jakarta-servlet-ht/65704617#65704617) (this answer contains complete examples of proper `pom.xml` declarations for Tomcat 10+, Tomcat 9-, JEE 9+ and JEE 8-).

Comment: Hi @BalusC , thank you so much. you solve my problem.

Comment: I had also to delete and recreate the server in Eclipse, after updating the project, I don't know why. But looks ok now.

Answer (score 40):

While the cleanest solutions are those given by BalusC (i.e. always deploy your application on the platform it was designed to run), since Tomcat 10.0.4 there is a workaround that allows deployment of Servlet 4.0 applications on Tomcat 10.

You just need to modify your context description in `conf\Catalina\localhost\[contextname].xml` (in your case `[contextname]` is `VirtualStore`) and add:

```xml
<Context>
    ...
    <Loader jakartaConverter="TOMCAT" />
</Context>
```

(cf. [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/loader.html)).

This will convert (simple) Servlet 4.0 applications on-the-fly as an alternative to the [Tomcat Migration Tool for Jakarta EE](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi).

Comment: As my installation has no "VirtualStore.xml", I just added the Loader line to the context.xml of the Tomcat installation, restarted and now works.

Comment: I am using tomcat 10.0.27 with spring 5.3.23. I added it in conf/context.xml. 

It is working fine.