# Tomcat webapp not running

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm having trouble starting a webapp that works smoothly on TOMCAT 9, while in Tomcat 10.0.4 it just doesn't seem to want to start.
I have deployed the .war file and when I run the application, I report this error.

[image]

I have activated the DEBUG log, but nothing comes up. I can't understand what the problem is. On TOMCAT 9 it works great. has anything changed from TOMCAT 9 to 10?

The application makes only and exclusively use of API

Comment: is.war deployment success? if not share the error messages

Comment: yes, the deployment of the .war file is successful without errors. not even in the log I have errors. it's very strange.

Comment: check if there are typo in URL and port

Comment: url and port are correct, in fact on TOMCAT 9 with the exact same configuration it works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 10.x throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66711660/tomcat-10-x-throws-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-javax-servlet-servletreques)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tomcat 10.0.x requires Java 8 or later. This is unchanged from Tomcat 9.0.x.

Comment: both on TOMCAT 9 and TOMCAT 10 I am using in the jdk 8

Comment: then your port issue because error 404 occur when port or url not correct

Comment: which port should i configure? On TOMCAT 9 I have the exact same settings.

Comment: This should be a Comment, not a Answer.

Comment: The 404 status indicated that the tomcat don’t find the ressource for the URL.
You must see the log of the tomcat server.

Comment: @BasilBourque I am new so Currently, I am not able to  comment on a post

Comment: @Enjy There is nothing in the TOMCAT logs about deploying the WAR, nothing reporting this problem.