# Spring Boot embedded Tomcat server not starting in intellij idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am facing issue while running my newly created spring boot application using spring initializer.
The embedded tomcat is failing to start with below error

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
> start embedded Tomcat server

Below is the full exception stack trace message while running the application

```
SnapShooter listening on port 57894

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-04-25 11:48:44.048  INFO 2372 --- [           main] e.T.TransactionManagementBootApplication : Starting TransactionManagementBootApplication using Java 1.8.0_212 on DESKTOP-8UK0JH5 with PID 2372 (D:\core-java-practice-programs\Gradle_Practice\TransactionManagementBoot\target\classes started by dell in D:\core-java-practice-programs\Gradle_Practice)
2021-04-25 11:48:44.051  INFO 2372 --- [           main] e.T.TransactionManagementBootApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-25 11:48:44.866  INFO 2372 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-25 11:48:44.880  INFO 2372 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-25 11:48:45.827  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8085 (http)
2021-04-25 11:48:45.837  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-25 11:48:45.837  INFO 2372 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-25 11:48:45.980  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-25 11:48:45.980  INFO 2372 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1865 ms
2021-04-25 11:48:46.028  INFO 2372 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-25 11:48:46.195  INFO 2372 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-25 11:48:46.202  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:ashok'
2021-04-25 11:48:46.448  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-25 11:48:46.502  INFO 2372 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-25 11:48:46.616  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-25 11:48:46.722  INFO 2372 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-04-25 11:48:47.222  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-25 11:48:47.231  INFO 2372 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-25 11:48:47.279  WARN 2372 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-25 11:48:47.414  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-25 11:48:47.660  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Marking servlet [jsp] as unavailable
2021-04-25 11:48:47.662  WARN 2372 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-04-25 11:48:47.664  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-25 11:48:47.664  INFO 2372 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-25 11:48:47.664  INFO 2372 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2021-04-25 11:48:47.670  INFO 2372 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-25 11:48:47.671  INFO 2372 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-04-25 11:48:48.013  INFO 2372 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-04-25 11:48:48.041  INFO 2372 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-04-25 11:48:48.056 ERROR 2372 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.example.TransactionManagementBoot.TransactionManagementBootApplication.main(TransactionManagementBootApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.snapShooter.SnapShooter.main(SnapShooter.java:58) [uiDesigner.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Servlet [jsp] in web application [] threw load() exception
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2897) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:305) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:216) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Class [org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet] is not a Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1047) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    ... 40 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Pom.xml file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TransactionManagementBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TransactionManagementBoot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Run config is as below

[Run Config Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhmcL.jpg)

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I would try to remove both tomcat-jasper, jakarta.servlet.jsp-api if you don't need them

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `embedded tomcat` in spring boot, you must change your dependency libriary `tomcat-jasper` to `tomcat-embed-jasper`.

There is `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in `spring-boot-starter-web`. you can see [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.5/jar).

There is `tomcat-embed-core` in `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` to use `embedded tomcat`. you can see [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.4.5/jar).

`embed-jaspser` which includes dependency with `tomcat-embed-core`. you can see [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/10.0.5/jar).

The `tomcat-jasper` you used is unnecessary because it doesn't include with dependency `tomcat-embed-core`. you can see [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper/10.0.5/jar).

Comment: I agree that `tomcat-embed-jasper` should be used instead of `tomcat-jasper`: the jars are 95% similar, but `tomcat-embed-jasper` has a dependency on `tomcat-embed-core` (already included by `spring-boot-starter`) so the Maven project will not pull a useless `tomcat-catalina` and `tomcat-util` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The version of JSP that comes with Tomcat 10 is **not** compatible with the embedded Tomcat 9: Tomcat 9 is a Servlet 4.0 servlet container, while Tomcat 10 is a Servlet 5.0 servlet container (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66711660/11748454)).

Therefore you should use a version of Jasper compatible with your version of Tomcat. Since `spring-boot-starter-parent` manages the versions of Tomcat dependencies, just delete the `<version>` property:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and remove the `jakarta.servlet.jsp-api` dependency.

**Edit:** Remark also that the scope of `tomcat-embed-jasper` should be `provided` so Spring Boot will not package it into `WEB-INF/lib` (it will put it into `WEB-INF/lib-provided` instead) and you will not encounter version conflicts if you deploy the project to an external Tomcat.

You can find the list of artifacts for which Spring Boot manages the versions in the [`spring-boot-dependencies`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.4.5/spring-boot-dependencies-2.4.5.pom) POM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I dont know why but when I put spring-boot-starter-web dependency first in the dependency list in the pom file it got resolved on its own! Please confirm if this works for anyone else too.

Comment: Please post step by step guide how you did this.