# Using JAX-RS on Tomcat 10.1

Tags: maven, tomcat, jax-rs

I am trying to migrate from Tomcat 9 to Tomcat 10.1 and my RESTful Webservices are not working anymore. I researched and I found out, that jakarta replaced javax. Which is fine, if it would be a quick fix, but the migration is quite hard. So I just tried to find some examples in the internet and was not able to find a lot, so I tried to create a new project to test it. Unfortunately, it is not working. I suppose the issue is the pom.xml. Can anyone help me here and verify mine?

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HelloWorld</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
   <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
   <version>9.0.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.security.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>20</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml
No web.xml, do I need one? I found a lot of examples without one, but I had one on Tomcat9 + javax

App.java:

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class App extends Application {
}
```

Hello.java:

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

   @GET
   public String sayHello() {
      return "Hello World";
   }
}
```

Thanks a lot!
Jan

Edit: before I did use Jersey

Comment: First step is to remove `jakarta.jakartaee-web-api`. This will only cause big confusion because Tomcat is **not** a JEE server. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65703840. Second step is to manually install JAX-RS. But you forgot to tell which JAX-RS impl you was originally using. Jersey? RESTEasy? Etc. Once you figure out that then you'll easier find answer to that in existing questions. E.g. just search using keywords "jersey maven tomcat 10".

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I did use jersey before

Comment: `jakarta.jakartaee-web-api` could technically stay, but as it combines a bunch of other API jars into itself, it will clash with the servlet and EL jars you've also declared in your pom file. If you were using Jersey before, there's like a Jakarta-compatible newer version of Jersey you can switch to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by updating the plugin section of the pom file:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <args>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${endorsed.dir}</args>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I cannot explain why, but this helped.