# <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> NOT RECOGNIZED

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-migration

I wanted to add a JSP file to my Spring MVC project, but the first line has not been recognized and has shown an error since the creation of the file.
Also the "status.index" is always equal to 0 (I think it's related to the import problem).

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Contact manager home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Contact List</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <c:forEach var="contact" items="${listContact}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                    <td>${contact.name}</td>
                    <td>${contact.email}</td>
                    <td>${contact.address}</td>
                    <td>${contact.phone}</td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</html>
```

Any suggestions please? (I tried all the available solutions for this problem in StackOverflow but they didn't work)

I tried to check the config of eclipse IDE and added maven dependencies and none of them work.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.codejava.contact</groupId>
    <artifactId>ContactManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring.version>6.0.12</spring.version>
        <cglib.version>3.3.0</cglib.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What does "not recognized" mean? What is the error message you're getting? What's the symptom of this?

Comment: @nitind "Not recognized" mean a syntax error pointed to the line where the error occured.

Comment: When you right-click on the file and open its **Properties** dialog, does the **Resource** page say the Type is "File  (JSP)"? If this same error shows up in the **Problems** View, what is the Type column's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank yuo for taking time to check the problem, actually I had to check the maven dependencies and changing the javax.servlet.jsp-api dependency to 2.3.3

Comment: Nope. This is also wrong. JSP 2.3 is for Tomcat 9.x only. You need JSP 3.0 for Tomcat 10.0.x and JSP 3.1 for Tomcat 10.1.x and, most importantingly, it must be `<scope>provided</scope>`. Your existing Servlet 6.0 dependency must also be marked `provided`. Otherwise you still end up with duplicate and conflicting classes in runtime classpath. See also the top ranked answer of the abovelinked duplicate for an in depth explanation how exactly to properly configure pom.xml for Tomcat and why exactly it's different for Tomcat than for normal JEE servers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65704617/157882