Persist a java object with EntityManager
I am trying to save an object to my database using Entity Manager in my Tomcat application but I am having some trouble with getting it to work because my DAO instance is null.
This is my code
User.java
This is the Entity I am trying to persist
package ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}


UserServlet.java
package ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.servlet;

import ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.dao.UserDao;
import ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.entity.User;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/user")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    UserDao userDao; // This gives me a null exception when I execute my servlet

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("achraf");
        userDao.save(user);
    }
}

UserDao.java
package ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.dao;

import ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.entity.User;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

// I found in some code samples this annotation @Stateless but I can get it here

public class UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "default")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }
}


Persistance.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default">

        <class>ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.entity.User</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projetjee"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1341"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

index.jsp
a simple form to trigger the servlet doPost method
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="user" method="post">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ma.ac.iga</groupId>
    <artifactId>jee_with_spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jee_with_spring</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

The error message
Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.dao.UserDao.save(ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.entity.User)" because "this.userDao" is null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.dao.UserDao.save(ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.entity.User)" because "this.userDao" is null
    ma.ac.iga.jee_with_spring.servlet.UserServlet.doPost(UserServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

If anyone can help me? Thanks
T tried to do it like this inside the servlet
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
user user = new user();
em.persist(user);
em.getTransaction().commit();

But I get an error no suitable driver for mysql but I have it on my projet and it works fine when I run this code in main function

You have it on your project but it's not included in your pom.xml?

Firstly you should fix your error with the driver. Here's the answer how to do this.

Just use a normal JEE server instead of Tomcat and then you'll find that among others JPA and CDI work out the box without pumping your pom.xml with yet more dependencies. Your DAO is null because @Inject doesn't work out the box in Tomcat. Food for reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65703840

unrelated but java package names should not contain underscores, maybe it is better to rename it "jeewithspring"
