Unable to load tag handler class [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.QueryTag] for tag [sql:query]
I am new to JSP pages. I am trying to use core Tags and sql tags in JSP using JSTL. But somehow I am getting the following error.Error 500 on Compilation
My JSP file is as follows:
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/advjava" user="root" password="${myPassword}"/>
    <sql:query var="rs" dataSource="${db}">SELECT * FROM books</sql:query>
    <c:forEach items="${rs.rows}" var="book">
        <c:out value="${book.book_name}" /> | <c:out value="${book.author_name}"/> | <c:out value="${book.publisher_name}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>

I have also added the dependency in my pom.xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Also, I would like to know if JSTL is actually deprecated, because I am not able work with it that smoothly.
I am trying to fetch the data from my MySQL database using JSTL tags. It is supposed to list down the book names, along with their author names and publisher name. I am trying to run a loop over the fetched data and display the required data.

According to stack trace, you have Apache's JSTL impl (standard.jar) or even a loose tld file somewhere in the runtime classpath. Get rid of them! See abovelinked duplicate. And no, JSTL is absolutely not deprecated. It's only that the <sql:foo> and <x:foo> tags are discommended for purposes other than quick prototyping. In real production apps you should use normal Java code instead, usually via a servlet. The <c:foo> tags and ${fn:foo()} are completely fine. See also among others https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/3.0/jakarta-tags-spec-3.0#sql-actions-sql-tag-library

Do note that when you have used a normal Jakarta EE server such as WildFly or GlassFish or TomEE or Liberty, etc from the beginning on instead of a barebones servletcontainer such as Tomcat, then you'd never have faced this kind of trouble as in "I am not able work with it that smoothly". You need to really clearly understand the fundaments behind that rather than blaming it to an imaginary deprecation. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65703840
