CDI is null with upgraded dev stack
I am switching from a single to a multi-tenant database. I wanted to make use of the '@TenantId' annotation in hibernate 6. In order to use hibernate 6 I needed to upgrade from java ee to jakarta ee. Which also required me to update Tomcat from 9 to 10.1.24. In addition I also upgraded from Java 8 to 21. Everything is working for me except for context dependency injection (CDI) which is RETURNING NULL to anything I'm trying to inject.
I am using a resource like so-
@Path("my-resource")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @Path("")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getList() {
        try {
            return Response.ok(myService.findAll(false)).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().entity("Error: This is where myService was null").build();
        }
    }

My service starts like so -
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyService implements Serializable { // followed by the function that never gets reached

Some things I've tried-
1.Added an empty beans xml with discovery mode all
2.Have tried both weld-servlet-shaded and openwebbeans pom dependencies
3.Have tried using an open webbeans listener inside the context xml
4.Have tried different types of annotations such as @RequestScoped or @ApplicationScoped
Looking for any suggestions or people who have updated their dev stack and might know of a few changes I missed.
FYI- I am using a Java backend with Maven architecture (Not Spring). Also not sure if I should be using weld or open web beans, not sure if it matters.

How to enable CDI in JAX-RS depends on the JAX-RS impl being used. But you forgot to tell which JAX-RS impl you're using. Tomcat doesn't provide anything of these so you had to manually install it as well. If you have no idea then show pom.xml of your attempt.

I have the jakarta.jakartaee-web-api 9.1.0 dependency in my pom, which I believe includes JAX-RS version 4.0.0. Thank you for the heads up, any information on how these things relate to each other is super helpful and hard to research.

Tomcat isn't a Jakarta EE server at all. Adding that dependency isn't going to magically convert Tomcat to a full fledged Jakarta EE compatible server. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65703840. You still haven't told which JAX-RS implementation you want to use on Tomcat. The mentioned jakartaee-web-api only contains the API. There are currently three active JAX-RS implementations: Jersey, RESTEasy and CXF. Which one are you using or do you want to use? You appear to be well aware of that wrt CDI: Weld and OWB are both examples of CDI implementations. The same applies to JAX-RS.

Okay gotcha, the pom file has RESTEasy version 6.2.8.Final. I did read somewhere that TomEE may be a better option that Tomcat but figured I'd stick with Tomcat as it starts up where TomEE threw new errors and I'm already over my head on this one. Happy to try anything to make it work at this point though.

OK, at the bottom of this RESTEasy manual you can find instructions to install/active its CDI module: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.8.Final/userguide/html/ch49.html Have you followed that? As to TomEE trouble: error messages are excellent search keywords. An alternative to TomEE is WildFly. It provides Weld and RESTEasy out the box without any additional config/dependencies.

@BalusC  I appreciate the direction this gave me! It looked like RESTEasy wasn't using Jakarta but Javax, so I switched to Jersey and after adding the right dependencies was able to get CDI working. Thanks for the help =)

Just to make this answer official, updating the dev stack was a huge pom file headache that also taught me a lot.
Solution-
Switch RESTEasy to Jersey. Jersey worked with Jakarta and I was able to get rid of the funny behavior. Looking through the Maven tree helped, but mostly a lot of switching out dependencies and trying to find the right versions that all played nicely together.
