CDI Weld3.1.6 configuration on Tomcat9 does not work
I'm struggling to create a jsf2.3 project using Weld3.1.6Final and deploying it on target runtime Tomcat9 running with java8.
Dinamic web module versione 4.0
Configurations:
java 1.8
JavaServer Faces 2.3
JSF Configurations and dependecies:
WEB-INF/faces-config.xml with version 2.3
WEB-INF/web.xml with version 4.0 and contains weld Listener and javax faces FacesServlet
WEB-INF/beans.xml (empty)
Those are my dependencies inside the WEB-INF/lib in my WAR file.
javax.faces-2.3.9.jar
javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.3.jar
javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar
weld-servlet-core-3.1.9.Final.jar
weld-environment-common-3.1.9.Final.jar
weld-core-impl-3.1.9.Final.jar
jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar
jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar
weld-spi-3.1.SP4.jar
weld-api-3.1.SP4.jar
weld-probe-core-3.1.9.Final.jar
jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api-2.0.2.jar
jakarta.inject-api-1.0.jar
cdi-api-2.0.SP1.jar
weld-jsf-3.1.9.Final.jar
weld-web-3.1.9.Final.jar
jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar
jboss-classfilewriter-1.2.5.Final.jar
javaee-web-api-8.0.jar

First of all I was using weld-servlet-shaded jar, I have removed it and use weld-servlet-core.
I receive the error
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
with
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager  at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.isJsf23(ApplicationImpl.java:2714)
For me it is very important to setting up this project because I need to do a porting with this restrictions and I'm relatively new to this technology.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated
----- UPDATE ----
After the @BalusC's advices, I have changed my pom in
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.security.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

The file beans.xml contains

bean-discovery-mode="all" version="2.0"

and I have a configuration class with the annotation

@FacesConfig(version = Version.JSF_2_3)

and now I receive antoher type of error, basically is

Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4714)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong
---- UPDATE ----
I found the problem, it was the Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0).
If I deploy the WAR directly on Tomcat it works, instead, if I use Eclipse, I receive the errors!!!
I've changed the Exlipse version in 2023-12 (4.30.0) and now it works!
Thanks a lot!

There are a lot of JARs in WEB-INF/lib which are conflicting each other and/or simply don't belong there. For a fully working Mojarra+Weld project for Tomcat (instead of a normal JEE server) you need only 2 of them: javax.faces.jar and weld-shaded.jar. The rest is either already provided by the server or already bundled into Mojarra/Weld JARs (for a normal JEE server you need zero of those JARs). Rinse and repeat. Also carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/a/65704617 when you're familier with Maven in order to properly understand what exactly the matter is with Tomcat.

Thank you for your answer.
I used all the dependecies ( provided ) present in the link (Tomcat 9.X section) with org.glassfish.javax.faces:2.3.9 and weld-servlet-shaded:3.1.6.Final ( the only two libraries in the folder WEB-INF/lib), and the error is changed.  Now I have
"Critical error during deployment:
javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager" and
"Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager"
any idea?

Several options: 1) upgrade to latest Mojarra 2.3 which is currently 2.3.21, or 2) use bean-discovery-mode=all in beans.xml, or 3) put @FacesConfig annotation on a some startup class. Please note that you usually cannot mix having pom.xml and manually carrying JARs in WEB-INF/lib. Use the one or the other. If you already have a pom.xml (i.e. your project is a real maven project) then remove all manually copypasted JARs from WEB-INF/lib and use  declarations instead.

Yes, my project is a maven project. I'm using beans.xml version 2.0 with bean-discovery-mode=all, I have a configuration class with @FacesConfig(version = Version.JSF_2_3). Sorry but I'm a little confused about these configurations. Anyway I tried to change javax.faces.2.3.9 with jakarta.faces.2.3.21 and I receive another types of error:
"Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory." and
"Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null".  Can I use the org.glassfish.jakarta.faces:2.3.21 with the other javax classes?

Remove all manually downloaded/copypasted JARs and exclusively use pom.xml. The jakarta.faces:2.3.21 and weld-shaded must have default scope (and the rest must have scope=provided). Of course JSF 2.3 is still javax.* package. The jakarta.* was only introduced in JSF 3.0. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8081234

Just to be sure, I removed the old one Tomcat9 and installed a new one, in this way the Tomcat's lib folder it should be correct. Inside my WEB-INF/lib I have only the two jars ( jakarta and weld-shaded ). I found the problem, is Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0). If I deploy the WAR directly on Tomcat it works, instead, if I use Eclipse, I receive the errors!!!
