java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
I always encounter this error when I start my Tomcat 10.1 server and send my API but after this error and send API again, the API works perfectly fine.
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [com.px.share.api.ApplicationConfig] in context with path [/pxservice] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1144)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:137)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:124)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:116)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(JsonMapperConfigurator.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(JsonMapperConfigurator.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.MapperConfiguratorBase._setAnnotations(MapperConfiguratorBase.java:123)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(JsonMapperConfigurator.java:53)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.locateMapper(ProviderBase.java:941)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._endpointForReading(ProviderBase.java:869)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:783)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:215)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:49)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1072)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:657)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:73)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:50)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:68)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:93)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:266)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:253)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:696)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:397)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:349)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:312)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

I already tried to run mvn dependency:tree to check if any of my project dependencies still use javax, but there is no clue at all here in my pom
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://www.maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.px</groupId>
    <artifactId>pxservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>pxservice</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <buildNumber>v.${project.version} build ${maven.build.timestamp}</buildNumber>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.8.0.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.security.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20211205</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-cells</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-imaging</artifactId>
            <version>24.7.1</version>
            <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-slides</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <classifier>jdk17</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>pxservice</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Note that I use Java 11 and Tomcat 10.1

JAXB has been removed from Java SE since version 9. Tomcat is not a JEE server and doesn't ship JAXB out the box. So you need to manually provide JAXB libs via pom.xml in case you want to use a non-JEE server on Java SE 9 or newer (similarly as you already did for JAX-RS because Tomcat also doesn't ship it out the box). Having jakarta.jakartaee-api as provided in pom.xml while targeting a non-JEE runtime is basically a lie. Be careful with that. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65703840

Something in your dependencies is pulling in and using the wrong Jackson module (the one expecting javax.xml.bind instead of jakarta.xml.bind).

I suggest taking a look here as to why the error happens:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java
And as the previous comments suggest, you most likely need to provide the dependencies yourself in the pom.xml.

Found this issue in jackson module which is related to your error : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/issues/153
The JsonMapperConfigurator is relying on JaxbAnnotationIntrospector which is javax-based introspector see here
For jakarta support, it would need some JakartaXmlBindAnnotationIntrospector which was introduced in jackson 2.13.0 release.
I guess if you can managed to change this from the first class to the second one, it could work as expected...
